# Setting country code ngx-intl-tel-input with angular 5

Tags: angular, ngx-international-phone-number

Trying to implement [ngx-intl-tel-input.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-intl-tel-input) But getting an error.

here is the [Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-intl-tel-input-demo-yial32) with some package changes.

please follow the versions of ngx-bootstrap, angular, and other related things. I think its a compatibility issue.

**Here are my packages:**

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/schematics": "0.0.35",
"@angular/animations": "^5.2.11",
"@angular/common": "^5.2.8",
"@angular/core": "^5.2.8",
"@angular/forms": "^5.2.8",
"@angular/http": "^5.2.8",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.8",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.8",
"@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.8",
"@angular/router": "^5.2.8",
"@nguniversal/express-engine": "^5.0.0-beta.6",
"@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^5.0.0",
"amazon-cognito-auth-js": "^1.0.0",
"amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^1.21.0",
"angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.5.1",
"bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta.2",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"express-http-proxy": "^1.1.0",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.6",
"intl-tel-input": "^16.0.7",
"jquery": "^3.2.1",
"ng2-pdf-viewer": "4.1.2",
"ngx-bootstrap": "^3.0.1",
"ngx-cookie-service": "^2.1.0",
"ngx-embed-video": "^0.3.0",
"ngx-intl-tel-input": "^2.0.7",
"ngx-quill": "^3.4.0",
"popper.js": "^1.12.6",
"primeng": "^5.2.4",
"quill": "^1.3.6",
"rxjs": "^5.4.2",
"ts-loader": "^3.5.0",
"typescript-base64-arraybuffer": "^0.1.0",
"zone.js": "^0.8.14"
```

}

**There is an error in the following line (file: node-modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm5/ngx-intl-tel-input.js):**

```
NgxIntlTelInputService.ngInjectableDef = ɵɵdefineInjectable({ factory: function NgxIntlTelInputService_Factory() { return new NgxIntlTelInputService(); }, token: NgxIntlTelInputService, providedIn: "root" });
```

**The error is:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
at eval (ngx-intl-tel-input.js:22)
at eval (ngx-intl-tel-input.js:24)
at Object../node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm5/ngx-intl-tel-input.js (vendor.bundle.js:3684)
at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)
at eval (app.module.ts:26)
at Object../src/app/app.module.ts (main.bundle.js:235)
at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)
at eval (main.ts:4)
at Object../src/main.ts (main.bundle.js:3515)
at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try version 2.0.4 or lower of `ngx-intl-tel-input`.

First, remove the previous installation and then:

```
npm i ngx-intl-tel-input@2.0.4
```

Comment: Ok, I will try and discuss it.

Comment: after adding 2.0.4, `SearchCountryField, TooltipLabel, CountryISO` these fields are not found in ngx-intl-tel-input

Comment: look at this stackblitz: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-intl-tel-input-demo?file=package.json

Comment: can you do a ng update on your app ? or maybe try another library instead I'll try to recreate your code in my machine

Comment: look at the stalkbiz. I am having the same issue in my machine. If we can solve it in stackbiz, then its solved

Comment: Hi , I was trying to fix the stackblitz and I manage to download the version of ngx-intl tel input to 1.0.6 but you get the error with countryISO and all other imports. you have two choices upgrade your angular core or install maybe this NPM https://github.com/kondi0/ng4-intl-phone/ to get it work,